# QueryOver: Dynamically adding IsLike in Where clause

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, queryover

I've this *QueryOver* where I select *Log* records where the Logs *Name* starts with *D* or *F* (using wildcards).

```
conv.InnerTransaction.Session.QueryOver<Log>()
    .Where(l => l.DateTime > _datetime)
    .And(
        l => l.Name.IsLike("D%") || l.Name.IsLike("F%")
     )
```

Instead I would like the name searching to be dynamically using values from a list. How can this be done?

I've tried something like:

```
var query = conv.InnerTransaction.Session.QueryOver<Log>()
            .Where(l => l.DateTime > _datetime);
foreach (var name in _names)
{
    query = query.And(l => l.Name.IsLike(name));
}
```

But that would result in multiple AND statements for each name in the list, whereas It just need to be a OR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `Disjunction`? I had a similar requirement  once, but I had to use `Conjunction` instead. `Disjunction` will `or` multiple conditions together.

```
var disjunction = new Disjunction();
var query = Session.QueryOver<Log>().Where(l => l.DateTime > _datetime);
foreach (var name in _names)
{
    disjunction.Add(Restrictions.On<Log>(log => log.Name).IsLike(name));
}
var queryResult = query.Where(disjunction).List<Log>();
```